# RegExp help (for PHP)

Tags: php, regex

I am working on a little "development" language for my personal use. I do not plan to make it advanced at all (although I don't know what will happen at later points), but I've run into a problem.

I am not very experienced with RegExp and I want to use it to check whatever a part of the code is defining a new variable or running function. In this case, I need a RegExp that will check if the user is defining a variable.

So, lets say I have a part like this: **$abcd = 5**

Now, the RegExp should meet the next criteria:
  - It should check if the first letter is "$" (that's easy: "\$")
  - Now, the letters after "$" (lets call them variable name) are the problem. Variable
    name can contain letters [a-z, A-Z], numbers [0-9] and underscores [_]
  - The next thing, space between the variable name and "=" can be infinitely long (it can
    be one space ( ), or a millions of spaces - that should make no difference
  - Than comes the equal sign (this is easy as well - "\=")
  - The same as in the third one applies for space after equal sign
  - And at the end variable value. There should be no RegExp validation for this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're looking to parse PHP you should look into the native functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not want to use regular expressions for a task like this. It will quickly turn into a nightmare. What you want is a simple grammar and a recursive-descent parser.

That being said, something like this should work:

```
/\$[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\s*=\s*[0-9]+$/
```

This will only match cases where you're assigning a number to variable. If you want to assign other values, you are going to have to make the regular expression more complicated (see what I meant about it turning into a nightmare? :) ). For example, if you want to assign a string value to your variable, the regex will be different. You will also have to take into account things like escaped quotes and concatenation. Doing these things with a regular expression is very difficult.

A simple grammar for function calls and variable definitions could look like this:

```
<program>             ::= { <statement> }
<statement>           ::= <function-call> | <variable-assignment>
<function-call>       ::= <identifier>, '(', [ <parameter-list> ], ')'
<identifier>          ::= <valid-starting-char>, { <valid-char> }
<valid-starting-char> ::= [A-Za-z_]
<valid-char>          ::= [A-Za-z]
<parameter-list>      ::= <identifier>, { ',', <identifier> }
<variable-assignment> ::= '$', <identifier>, '=', <value>
<value>               ::= <number> | <string>
<number>              ::= <digit>, { <digit> }
<string>              ::= '"', ( { <character> | <escaped-character> } ), '"'
<character>           ::= .
<escaped-character>   ::= '\', <character>
```

This grammar doesn't take into account concatenation, numbers with fractional values (i.e., after the decimal point), and negative numbers. But it's pretty simple and should give you a good starting point. There are many tutorials out there that tell you how to create a [recursive-descent](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CBkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FRecursive_descent_parser&rct=j&q=recursive%20descent%20parser&ei=Zyu3TeqYFbHdiAKe2Yg0&usg=AFQjCNF3qsAXDUtjPOpLUUqpDD3uIL3bQA&sig2=z6iLme_96wAJaZ99g_XKsg&cad=rja) parser from an [EBNF](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FExtended_Backus%25E2%2580%2593Naur_Form&rct=j&q=ebnf&ei=VCu3Td7ACKXYiAK0ofg9&usg=AFQjCNFnhlYcV1HOoVDCXMtLFPMIhcgE6Q&sig2=oTNZ4ymBJYBGEo7I2lITXA&cad=rja). You will still need to tokenize your input.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first off, if you're creating a language, you need a lexer to tokenize the string (based on regular expressions) and a parser to interpret the language (based on a grammar).

With that being said, your regex is:

```
\$[a-zA-Z_0-9]+[ \t\n]*=[ \t\n]*[0-9]+
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick note on the above replies:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_]
```

is the same as

```
\w
```